# Let y be an integer, if for some natural number n, $100 | y^n$ does $10|y$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let y be an integer, if for some natural number n, $100 | y^n$ does $10|y$? If so what does the proof look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A proof*: If $100$ divides $y^n$, then the prime numbers $2$ and $5$ divide $y$.

*Another proof*: If $100$ divides $y^n$ then the last digit of $y$ is $0$.